# Saving Swiper instance via React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, swiper.js

Tsx version of Swiper for React was released in summer 2020. Repeating the example of the official documentation, the slider breaks - even the styles refuse to work.

The main task is to add thumbs to the slider and link them. This means that you need to install the controller and thumbs modules, and then use the onSwiper method to specify who is attached to whom.

So, we expect this result (here without any binding to each other):
[Expected screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GnIf.png)

But we've got this:
[Incorrect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmEhn.png)

The only difference between them is that I do not call `onSwipe={setMainSwiper}` and `onSwipe={setThumbSwiper}` in the working version, where set*Name*Slider are `useState()` hooks. Of course, incorrect version doesn't work at all.

Code examples:

```js
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay, Controller, Lazy, Thumbs } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import SwiperClass from 'swiper/types/swiper-class';

SwiperCore.use([Autoplay, Controller, Lazy, Thumbs]);

...

const [mainSwiper, setMainSwiper] = useState<SwiperClass>();
const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState<SwiperClass>();

...

<Swiper
  spaceBetween={0}
  slidesPerView={1}
  preloadImages={false}
  onSwiper={setMainSwiper}
  thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
  controller={{ control: thumbsSwiper }}
  autoplay
  loop
  lazy
>
  {state?.Images.map(image => (
    <SwiperSlide key={uniqid()} className={styles.medium}>
      {getSlide('medium', image.Medium)}
    </SwiperSlide>
  ))}
</Swiper>

<Swiper
  spaceBetween={3}
  slidesPerView={5}
  preloadImages={false}
  onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
  controller={{ control: mainSwiper }}
  slideToClickedSlide
  watchSlidesVisibility
  watchSlidesProgress
  lazy
>
  {state?.Images.map(image => (
    <SwiperSlide key={uniqid()} className={styles.small}>
      {getSlide('small', image.Small)}
    </SwiperSlide>
  ))}
</Swiper>
```

And from official documentation:

```js
import SwiperCore, { Thumbs } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

// install Swiper's Thumbs component
Swiper.use([Thumbs]);

const App = () => {
  // store thumbs swiper instance
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);

  return (
    <main>
      {/* Main Swiper -> pass thumbs swiper instance */}
      <Swiper thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }} ...>
        {/* ... */}
      </Swiper>

      {/* Thumbs Swiper -> store swiper instance */}
      {/* It is also required to set watchSlidesVisibility and watchSlidesProgress props */ }
      <Swiper
        onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
        watchSlidesVisibility
        watchSlidesProgress
        ...
      >
        {/* ... */}
      </Swiper>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem try to change your code

```
const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);
```

to:

```
const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState<SwiperCore>();
```